# Does com.google.guava has backward compatibility?

Tags: java, hadoop, guava

I am getting Exception

*java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator*

When I search for such error, I found that this error occurs when compiled jar and executing Jar are different version.
My com.google.guava is 11.0.2. But I happens to check dependency hierachy. I found that hbase is also downloading guava dependency i.e. of 12.0.1
I think this may causing me error.

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.translateException(RpcRetryingCaller.java:229) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:140) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:889) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:855)

So I want to know if com.google.guava is backward compatibility?

Comment: See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Compatibility - it sounds like you probably just want to start using a more recent version of Guava. (11.02 is nearly 5 years old at this point...) If you're not using any beta/experimental features or ones which were deprecated, I'd expect it to be fine. If you *are* using functionality which was deprecated, now's probably a good time to fix that anyway.

Comment: Further StackTrace as,
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.translateException(RpcRetryingCaller.java:229)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:140)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:889)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:855)

Comment: That should be in the question, not in a comment - but my comment still stands...

Comment: Can you tell me which is best version which will suit for both hbase and spark.

Comment: No, I can't. That's work you need to do. But as I say, unless you're using functionality which has been removed in later builds, the latest should be fine. That's what I'd try first.

Comment: I tried the latest one but, got no use. same error. spark need guava 14.0.1 where as hbase need guava 12.0.1, thats what causing conflict I kept my version to 19.0.1,

Comment: I doubt that they need those exact versions - I would expect that so long as the right members are available, it would be okay. Are you using the most recent versions of both spark and hbase? (You hadn't even mentioned spark in the question...)

Comment: Sorry About that , Yes I am Using Latest version of both. one way I did is I include both version JAR of guava. But I don't think it is feasible solution.